# Tencent Cloud (QCloud) Identity and Access Management

Tags: amazon-iam

I am trying to add users to Tencent Cloud (QCloud) account, similar to one would do using AWS IAM.

Under "User Management" I added a user, but the user received an email indicating he is a collaborator and will receive notifications rather than the instruction on how to login to the account I created.

What is the Tencent Cloud equivalent of AWS IAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAM (Cloud Access Management) is the service you are looking for.
https://cloud.tencent.com/document/product/378/9027?lang=en

This functionality is currently available in Chinese now, and will will be extended to support English later this year.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of AWS IAM in qcloud is CAM.

You should create a sub account (子用户) instead of (collaborator) 协作者
https://console.qcloud.com/cam/user/userType

Collaborator requires the user to have a Tencent Cloud account first and then you grant access right of your tencent cloud account to that user. On the other hand, sub account allows the user to create an account without having a tencent cloud account.